# Probability inequality for lower bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Suppose that we have a non-negative random variable $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$, with mean $\mu>1$ and variance $\sigma^{2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$. And we found that $\mathbb{P}(0\leq X \leq 2)\geq 1/2$. Also we want to show that  the probability of $X$ being positive $\mathbb{P}(X>0)>\frac{1}{2}$. But I'm not sure how to do that

Is there any one-sided inequality except Chebyshev's and Markov, because I tried to prove it by using them and didn't help at all.

Also I was thinking that we may have to find the probability $\mathbb{P}(X=0)$ and then we can say something for $\mathbb{P}(X>0)=1-\mathbb{P}(X=0)$,(because X is positive).

Any idea would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$\mathbb{P}\{X = 0\} \geq \frac {1} {2}$$
Then consider
$$ \begin{align} 
\sigma^2 &= \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2|X = 0]\mathbb{P}\{X = 0\} + 
\mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2|X > 0]\mathbb{P}\{X > 0\} \\
&\geq \mu^2 \mathbb{P}\{X = 0\} \\
&\geq \frac {1} {2}
\end{align}$$
which lead a contradiction to the assumption that $\displaystyle \sigma^2 \geq \frac {1} {2}$. Therefore $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}\{X = 0\} < \frac {1} {2}$